# Service bus 1.1 for Windows Server Qeueu and Topic Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, servicebus

I tried to find scripts for creating Qeues and Topics but could not find any powershell ones. We had to skip WAP to handle it thorugh the portal because WAP returns SSL/TLS error when creating namespace, does not like the certificate we have for this customer.

Anyone have any made or know where to find scripts for this?

Thank you in advance,
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to use the custom certificates and solve it in another way.
We will use Windows Azure Pack Portals to handle the Queues and Topics, so this matter is resolved.